# Multiple Highslide Galleries with Thumbstrip

Tags: highslide

I'm using highslide and want to have a page with a number of small galleries on it covering different subjects. I've got one gallery working perfectly, but when I create more galleries the images from all the different galleries show in the one thumbstrip. How can i ensure the galleries are kept separate? I'm sure this is incredibly simple but i'm struggling with it.

At the moment my first two gallery codes are as follows:

```
<div class="servicebox">
        <h2>Radiators</h2>
      <div class="highslide-gallery">
        <a class='highslide' id="thumb1" href='assets/photos/radiators/01.jpg' title="" onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
          <img src='assets/photos/radiators/01_thm.jpg' alt=''/>
        </a>          
      <div class="hidden-container">
        <a class='highslide' href='assets/photos/radiators/02.jpg' title="" onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
          <img src='assets/photos/radiators/02_thm.jpg' alt=''/>
        </a>
        <a class='highslide' href='assets/photos/radiators/03.jpg' title="" onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
          <img src='assets/photos/radiators/03_thm.jpg' alt=''/>
        </a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="servicebox">
        <h2>Bathrooms</h2>
      <div class="highslide-gallery">
        <a class='highslide' id="thumb1" href='assets/photos/bathrooms/01.jpg' title="" onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
          <img src='assets/photos/bathrooms/01_thm.jpg' alt=''/>
        </a>          
      <div class="hidden-container">
        <a class='highslide' href='assets/photos/bathrooms/02.jpg' title="" onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
          <img src='assets/photos/bathrooms/02_thm.jpg' alt=''/>
        </a>
        <a class='highslide' href='assets/photos/bathrooms/03.jpg' title="" onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
          <img src='assets/photos/bathrooms/03_thm.jpg' alt=''/>
        </a>
        <a class='highslide' href='assets/photos/bathrooms/04.jpg' title="" onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
          <img src='assets/photos/bathrooms/04_thm.jpg' alt=''/>
        </a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

EDIT:
I've figured this out now. I just needed to set up a couple of new option sets in the config area like so:

```
    var miniGalleryOptions1 = {
    thumbnailId: 'thumb1',
    slideshowGroup: 1
}

var miniGalleryOptions2 = {
    thumbnailId: 'thumb2',
    slideshowGroup: 2
}
```

and then change the return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions2) code to the relevant gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference - see this Highslide FAQ: [How do I put more than one gallery in the same page?](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=4682)